# json_decode() returns different values on different environment

Tags: php, json, json-deserialization

This is quite puzzling for me, and I do not understand why this is happening.

On my localhost which is running Windows 8.1 Enterprise Edition with PHP 5.6.15 on XAMPP

```
<?php var_dump(json_decode('26-10-2017'));
```

returns

```
NULL
```

while on a Linode box running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with PHP 5.5.9 on LAMP (running Sentora Panel)

I get

```
int(26)
```

I would be much indebted to anyone who can explain me this phenomenon.

I know this is not valid JSON, however, my intention is to learn what is causing this difference in output and how to avoid this.

---

I tried `json_last_error()`, in fact I was trying

```
function isValidJSON($string) {
    json_decode($string);
    return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}
```

However, it does not seem to show any errors.

```
<?php var_dump(json_decode('26-10-2017')); var_dump(json_last_error());
```

Returns

```
int(26)
int(0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: That isn't valid JSON to begin with. The question why it returns different values is interesting (perhaps HHVM vs. PHP proper, and/or different versions…?), but ultimately this shouldn't work at all.

Comment: FWIW, only some 5.2.x versions return anything other than `null` here: https://3v4l.org/Y0DEH - which is a PHP bug either way.

Answer (score 0):

Check [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) which will returns the last error (if any) occurred during the last JSON encoding/decoding.

I hope you'll find some interesting facts :) **Cheerse!!**

Comment: I did try that, in fact I was trying 

function isValidJSON($string) {
    json_decode($string);
    return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}

However, it does not seem to show any errors. Returns int(0). Thanks!

Comment: You're returning boolean expression so it only return `1` or `0`, instead of that return `json_last_error()` or `echo` out